# VS2015 Universal APP - Could not load assembley (badimageformatexception)

Tags: win-universal-app, badimageformatexception, visual-studio-2015

Error to call any method of System.Threading , System.IO or System.ReflectionTypeExtensions that have been imported from nuguet in a universal app aplication, underneath have a exemple :

Call :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var thread = Thread.CurrentThread; 
}
```

Error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Thread, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
or one of its dependencies.
Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution. 
They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)
```

Comment: Can you add more information about what you are trying to do?

Comment: I start a new universal app project in the visual studio 2015  , add by nuget a System.Threading.Thread and call the method